# Macro function call missing argument warning, even when given an argument

Tags: c++, c, visual-c++

I've written a simple macro to throw a break point in Visual Studio when it is hit in `Debug` configuration:

```
#ifdef _MSC_VER
#   define FLING_BREAK()    __debugbreak
#endif  // _MSC_VER
```

An example of how I invoke it is:

```
FLING_BREAK();
```

However, this results in `warning C4551:  function call missing argument list`

I have tried changing the macro a couple of different ways:

```
#ifdef _MSC_VER
#   define FLING_BREAK(...) __debugbreak
#endif  // _MSC_VER
```

and

```
#ifdef _MSC_VER
#   define FLING_BREAK(str) __debugbreak
#endif  // _MSC_VER
```

And they result in warnings about missing argument lists, even when I give a string:

```
FLING_BREAK("This shouldn't warn?"); // throws warning C4551
```

Any idea how to solve this while still keeping the same syntax for calling this macro? I don't get this warning on GCC or Clang 8.0, only in MSVC. Thanks!

Comment: `__debugbreak` is a function and needs `()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`__debugbreak()` is [declared as](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/intrinsics/debugbreak?view=vs-2019):

```
void __debugbreak();
```

When you use

```
FLING_BREAK();
```

it expands to

```
__debugbreak;
```

i.e. you are not making the function call. That's what the compiler is warning about. Change your macro to:

```
#   define FLING_BREAK()    __debugbreak()
```